# Why does simple animation cause a very long update layer tree?

Tags: performance, animation, svg, layout, google-chrome-devtools

Paste this code on any site with a heavy interface (twitter for example) and run a performance test:

```
<div style="position: absolute; contain: strict; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; z-index: 2000; top: 0; left: 0; background: white; backface-visibility: hidden;">
   <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="40px">
      <rect width="40" height="40" x="93.5319">
         <animate attributeName="x" dur="1000ms" repeatCount="indefinite" from="0" to="100"></animate>
      </rect>
   </svg>
</div>
```

For incomprehensible reasons to me, the "update layer tree" takes several ms on the core i7 4770k:
[example on twitter.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH7c1.png)

And if you insert the same code on an empty page, then everything works very quickly. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: overflow visible means that potentially the svg may cause the whole page to change. It's generally a performance killer. Does removing it or if necesary setting overflow="hidden" fix things?

Comment: No, this does not solve the problem. I specially wrapped svg in a div with the contain: strict. This is clearly not the case.

Comment: Looks like Chrome doesn't properly optimize containment.

Comment: @LordGuard - were you able to find any answers to this question?